# Find the minimum of the function $y=\sqrt{-x^2+4x+21}+\sqrt{-x^2+3x+10}.$

Tags: optimization, radicals, alternative-proof, maxima-minima, convexity-inequality

Find the minimum of the function $$y=\sqrt{-x^2+4x+21}+\sqrt{-x^2+3x+10}.$$

---

By computer I found $\min_y=3;$ then I will prove $y\ge 3$. After squaring we got $$(x+2)(178-37x)\ge 0\quad \forall -2\le x\le 5.$$

My idea is not beautiful so I need some other solution. Thanks!

Comment: How about rationalizing
$$\sqrt{-x^2 + 4x + 21} + \sqrt{-x^2 + 3x + 10},$$
which you obtain via multiplying this by
$$\frac{\sqrt{-x^2 + 4x + 21} - \sqrt{-x^2 + 3x + 10}}{\sqrt{-x^2 + 4x + 21} - \sqrt{-x^2 + 3x + 10}}?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{-x^2+4x+21}+\sqrt{-x^2+3x+10}.$

Thus, $f$ is a concave function, which gives
$$\min_{[-2,5]}f=\min\{f(-2),f(5)\}=f(-2)=3.$$
I used the following obvious statement.

> Let $g(x)=\sqrt{f(x)},$ where $f$ is a concave twice differentiable function on $\{x|f(x)\geq0\}.$
>
> Prove that $g$ is a concave function.

Comment: It should be noted that $-x^2+3x+10=-(x+2)(x-5)$ and $-x^2+4x+21=-(x+3)(x-7),$ so $f$ is defined for $x\in[-2,5]$

Comment: @J. W. Tanner I think, it's not necessary. See please the starting post.

Comment: But how would you prove that this function is concave without going into some messy details.

Comment: @Anurag A I added something. See now. I am ready to explain more. Thank you for your interest!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg First of all I would beg to differ when you termed the added statement as "obvious". Secondly, you are also using the fact that the sum of two concave functions is concave etc.. All these, while true, still seems to be using lot of machinery. It may give a false sense of comfort about the solution for the problem. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Anurag A  It's indeed obvious that $f''(x)\leq0$ and $f'(x)^2\geq0.$  I really don't understand you. About your second statement. I used also that a sum of two real numbers it's a real number and more and more...

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks for taking the time to respond. I was referring to the "general" statement that you have mentioned in blockquote. I am not questioning your application of it. The proof of that result is not as obvious as you have stated (composition of concave functions etc..). Moreover OP's function $f=\sqrt{f_1}+\sqrt{f_2}$ and you have used the result on each component but then claimed that $f$ is concave, while true, it is not simply adding two real numbers. You are using the fact that sum of two concave functions is concave and that is what I pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

Let
\begin{align*}
f_1(x)&=\sqrt{-x^2+4x+21}\\
f_2(x)&=\sqrt{-x^2+3x+10}.
\end{align*}
An examination of the domains of each of these functions separately shows that 
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{D}(f_1)&=[-3,7]\\
\mathcal{D}(f_2)&=[-2,5].
\end{align*}
If we define $f(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x),$ then the above forces the domain $\mathcal{D}(f)=[-2,5].$ Therefore, we must evaluate the function $f$ at $-2$ and $5$. However, there may be critical points inside the domain. Differentiating $f$ yields
$$f'(x)=\frac{2-x}{\sqrt{-x^2+4x+21}}+\frac{3/2-x}{\sqrt{-x^2+3x+10}}. $$
Setting this equal to zero yields the following:
\begin{align*}
(2-x)\sqrt{-x^2+3x+10}&=(x-3/2)\sqrt{-x^2+4x+21}\\
(2-x)^2(-x^2+3x+10)&=(x-3/2)^2(-x^2+4x+21)\\
&\vdots\\
51x^2-104x+29&=0\\
x&=\frac{29}{17},\;\frac{1}{3},
\end{align*}
both of which are in $\mathcal{D}(f).$ However, plugging $1/3$ into $f'(x)$ shows that we picked up a spurious root by squaring. Evaluating, then, we have
\begin{align*}
f(-2)&=3 \\
f\left(\frac{29}{17}\right)&=6\sqrt{2}\approx 8.49 \\
f(5)&=4.
\end{align*}
This proves that the minimum occurs at $x=-2,$ and has a value of $y=3.$

Comment: I think you meant $x=-\color{red}2$

Comment: Oh, right. That was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demonstration -- not using calculus or concavity arguments --

that the minimum of $y=\sqrt{-x^2+4x+21}+\sqrt{-x^2+3x+10}$ is $3$.

Note that $y=\sqrt{-(x-7)(x+3)}+\sqrt{-(x-5)(x+2)}=\sqrt{5^2-(x-2)^2}+\sqrt{\left(\dfrac72\right)^2-\left(x-\dfrac32\right)^2}.$

So $y$ is defined when $-2\le x\le5$ or $\left(x-\dfrac32\right)^2\le\left(\dfrac72\right)^2.  $

When that is the case, $-2\le x\le 6$ or $\left(x- 2\right)^2\le4^2.  $

Therefore, $y= \sqrt{5^2-(x-2)^2}+\sqrt{\left(\dfrac72\right)^2-\left(x-\dfrac32\right)^2}\ge\sqrt{5^2-(x-2)^2}\ge\sqrt{5^2-4^2}=3,$

and note that $y=3$ when $x=-2$.